# Registration form not writing to database

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to make a registration form and I want to save the data the user inputs, but when I run the app and check my database on Firebase nothing is there, I already made sure that my database is connected to this app, but still I'm not getting anything,  here's what I have so far:

```
package com.example.parkingapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "RegisterPage";

    private EditText fName, lName, userEmail, userPassword, pNumber,schoolName;
    private Button registerBtn;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myReference = database.getReference("https://authenticate-user-443f2.firebaseio.com/");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration_activity);

        fName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_name);
        lName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.last_name);
        userEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_address);
        userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        pNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
        schoolName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.school_name);
        registerBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_user);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //  @Override
        //public void onClick(View v) {
        //  RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
        //}
        //});

        registerBtn.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
    }

       // registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         //   @Override
           // public void onClick(View v) {
             //   RegisterActivity.this.finish();
            //}
        //});

        //registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          //  @Override
            //public void onClick(View v) {
              //  RegisterActivity.this.registerUser();
            //}
        //});

    //}


    public void onClick(View view){
        if(view == registerBtn) {
            registerUser();
        }
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        final String firstName = fName.getText().toString();
        final String lastName = lName.getText().toString();
       final String email = userEmail.getText().toString();
        final String password = userPassword.getText().toString();
        final String phoneNumber = pNumber.getText().toString();
        final String school = schoolName.getText().toString();


        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            showToast("Enter email address!");
            return;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            showToast("Enter Password!");
            return;
        }

        if(userPassword.length() < 6){
            showToast("Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters");
            return;
        }


        //register user
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "New user registration: " + task.isSuccessful());

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                           // RegisterActivity.this.showToast("Authentication failed. " + task.getException());
                            DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("https://authenticate-user-443f2.firebaseio.com/");
                            DatabaseReference firstN =  ref.child("first name");
                            firstN.setValue(firstName);
                            DatabaseReference lastN =  ref.child("last name");
                            lastN.setValue(lastName);
                            DatabaseReference emailAddress =  ref.child("email");
                            emailAddress.setValue(email);
                            DatabaseReference password =  ref.child("password");
                            password.setValue(password);
                            DatabaseReference phone =  ref.child("phone number");
                            phone.setValue(phoneNumber);
                            DatabaseReference schoolName =  ref.child("school");
                            schoolName.setValue(school);


                        } else {
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class));
                            RegisterActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    public void showToast(String toastText) {
        Toast.makeText(this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Here is the log cat:
[image]

Comment: Please post the log cat.

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the log cat. @Ashish

Comment: does this `Log.d(TAG, "New user registration: " + task.isSuccessful());` log show ?

Comment: no, i don’t think it shows up. i made sure that firebase was connected to the right app and checked the log cat but i’m not getting that message. @Ashish

Answer (score 0):

You should use getReferenceUrl :

> Gets a DatabaseReference for the provided URL.

```
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReferenceUrl("https://authenticate-user-443f2.firebaseio.com/");
```

or

> Gets a DatabaseReference for the database root node.

```
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
```

---

Then which user do you want to set value?(Unknown) You have to set a user id(unique id).

```
ref.child("users").child("user_id").child("first name").setValue(firstName);
```

I think you should create user object. It would be more useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the data from your form into the Firebase database, would recommend to do something similar to this:

You are trying to save data from register form so the data structure will be the same every time. Create new object with the fields you want to save into database (example with 2 fields is given below):

```
 public class User {
    private String username;
    private String email;

    public User() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public User(String username, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

As your app is connected with database you don't need to provide the url. You can just simply use the statement:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("user_id");
```

After that, connect the fields from layout to variables:

```
Button registerBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_button);
EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
EditText userEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mail);
```

Then, on register button click you can get the data from the EditText fields and pass them to another function.

```
registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = userName.getText().toString();
                String mail = userEmail.getText().toString();
                pushNewUser(name, mail);
            }
        });
```

Last step is to set values into the database.

```
private void pushNewUser(String name, String email){
        User newUser = new User(name, email);
        mDatabase.setValue(newUser);
    }
```

To add more fields you have to add them into the User.java (don't forget about costructor/getters/setters) and then pass more values in pushNewUser function.